# error when filtering input using reactive

Tags: shiny

I get an error with this part of the app. I am not sure what is wrong here:

```
 data_selected <- reactive({filter(data_prep.miRNA, miRNA %in% input$MicroRNA) })
```

Here is my app:

```
library(dplyr) 
require(survminer)
library(tidyverse)
require(reshape2)
library(shiny)
library(tidyr)
require(survival)
```

example data:

```
 df.miRNA.cpm <-     structure(list(`86` = c(5.57979757386892, 17.0240095264258, 4.28380151026145, 
13.0457611762755, 12.5531123449841), `175` = c(5.21619202802748, 
15.2849097474841, 2.46719979911461, 10.879496005461, 9.66416497290915
), `217` = c(5.42796072966512, 17.1413407297933, 5.15230233060323, 
12.2646127361351, 12.1031024927547), `394` = c(-1.1390337316217, 
15.1021660424984, 4.63168157763046, 11.1299079134792, 9.55572588729967
), `444` = c(5.06134249676025, 14.5442494311861, -0.399445049232868, 
7.45775961504073, 9.92629675808998)), row.names = c("hsa_let_7a_3p", 
"hsa_let_7a_5p", "hsa_let_7b_3p", "hsa_let_7b_5p", "hsa_let_7c_5p"
), class = "data.frame")

df.miRNA.cpm$miRNA <- rownames(df.miRNA.cpm)


  ss.survival.shiny.miRNA.miRNA <-   structure(list(ID = c("86", "175", "217", "394", "444"), TimeDiff = c(71.0416666666667, 
601.958333333333, 1130, 1393, 117.041666666667), Status = c(1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Joint the two example data frames:

```
 data_prep.miRNA <- df.miRNA.cpm %>% 
tidyr::pivot_longer(-miRNA, names_to = "ID") %>% 
left_join(ss.survival.shiny.miRNA.miRNA)
```

Example of the joined data:

```
 > data_prep.miRNA
# A tibble: 153,033 x 5
   miRNA         ID     value TimeDiff Status
   <chr>         <chr>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <int>
 1 hsa_let_7a_3p 86     5.58      71.0      1
 2 hsa_let_7a_3p 175    5.22     602.       1
 3 hsa_let_7a_3p 217    5.43    1130        0
 4 hsa_let_7a_3p 394   -1.14    1393        0
 5 hsa_let_7a_3p 444    5.06     117.       1
 6 hsa_let_7a_3p 618    4.37    1508        0
 7 hsa_let_7a_3p 640    2.46    1409        0
 8 hsa_let_7a_3p 829    0.435    919.       0
 9 hsa_let_7a_3p 851   -1.36     976.       0
10 hsa_let_7a_3p 998    3.87    1196.       0
# … with 153,023 more rows
```

Shiny:

```
ui.miRNA <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("MicroRNA", "miRNA", choices = unique(data_prep.miRNA$miRNA)),

  plotOutput("myplot"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data_selected <- reactive({
    filter(data_prep.miRNA, miRNA %in% input$MicroRNA)
  })
  
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
      fitSurv <-   survfit(Surv(TimeDiff, Status) ~ cut(value, quantile(value, probs = c(0, .4, .8)), include.lowest=TRUE),data = data_selected())

    ggsurvplot(fitSurv)
    
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui.miRNA, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working `server` function. The problem was that the `data` argument in `ggsurvplot` was missing:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data_selected <- reactive({
    filter(data_prep.miRNA, miRNA %in% input$MicroRNA)
  })
  
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    fitSurv <-   survfit(Surv(TimeDiff, Status) ~ cut(value,
                                                      quantile(value, probs = c(0, .4, .8)),
                                                      include.lowest=TRUE),
                         data = data_selected())
    
    ggsurvplot(fitSurv, data = data_selected())
    
    
  })
}
```

BTW: I got slightly different error messages. You can make your code a bit more foolproof if you add `req` functions to check if the needed inputs are ready, e.g.:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data_selected <- reactive({
    req(input$MicroRNA)
    filter(data_prep.miRNA, miRNA %in% input$MicroRNA)
  })

  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    req(data_selected())
    fitSurv <-   survfit(Surv(TimeDiff, Status) ~ cut(value,
                                                      quantile(value, probs = c(0, .4, .8)),
                                                      include.lowest=TRUE),
                         data = data_selected())

    ggsurvplot(fitSurv, data = data_selected())


  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So the data object needs to be in the plotting function as well.

Comment: Glad that I could help! A good way to debug shiny apps to find errors like these is to use `browser()` in different parts of the code to find out where the error occurs.

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to make the quantile as a slider in the selectInput? How would you define that in the survfit?

Comment: The complete quantile function or only the probabilities? It could be a bit difficult as you need to generate a sequence, I'm not sure if a slider is the best way to do it. If you don't find a solution, you can ask a new question.

Comment: Yes, the probs, from 0-1. I have not found a similar shiny that have done it.